# Flutter : click-and-drag items in a list

Tags: flutter, animation

i'm searching a widget to display a list of items and, with an animation, i would like to move the order of the items in the list with click-and-drag.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its already provide by flutter. You can create withour any addtional package with `ReorderableListView` .

[documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html):

> A list whose items the user can interactively reorder by dragging.

```
 ReorderableListView(
    buildDefaultDragHandles: false,
    onReorder:(int oldIndex, int newIndex){}
     children: []
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ReorderableListView Widget to this. Here is a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3fB1mxOsqJE) from Flutter Devs!